# how to change the postion of a FBXModel in three.js

Tags: three.js, fbx

I have loaded a fbxmodel to the localhost:8080 with threejs，and then i want to updata the model's attribute such as position with the code:

```
    loader.load( 'models/train/train2.fbx', function ( train ) {     
                        train.traverse( function ( child ) {
                            if ( child.isMesh ) {
                                child.castShadow = true;
                                child.receiveShadow = true;
                            }
                        } );
                        train.scale.set(0.03,0.03,0.03);
                        train.position.set(-150,-2,200);
                        train.name="train";//set a name so i can find it in animate()
                        scene.add( train );
                    });
```

```
    function trainMove(){
                    var train=scene.getObjectByName("train");
                    if(train.position.z<PosValue)
                    //I input a int as PosValue so i can change the modle's position,make it a animation.
                        train.position.z++;
                    else
                        train.position.z--;
                }
```

I used the `scene.getObjectByName("")` to get the modle i want to udate position,but console gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'positon' of undefined`when i run with chrome.
But I can use this method to get the train(my FBXModel) in chrome,[ConsolePicture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNS4j.png),how could i get the model and its positon.z?Thank you very much for your help.
Thanks for  jscastro's advice and here is the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/smellytrotter/pen/xxVxqzr), i'm sorry that i dont have a pro.

Comment: `loader.load` is asynchronous and your method is synchronous. It looks you are calling `trainMove` before the object is loaded. if you add a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on Fiddle or Codepen it'll be easier for others to help you to resolve the issue.

Comment: thank you  jscastro, and here is my codepen, sorry for without assets   [Codepen](https://codepen.io/smellytrotter/pen/xxVxqzr)